# C++03 macro definitions with variables and types?

Tags: c++, templates, macros, c++03

I am trying to simplify a library by adding a macro. I have been reading about all the different things that macros can accomplish, but have had no luck implementing something that works the way I intend.

I wrote a memory manager that is to be used with the placement new feature. It keeps track of what is allocated and where it is in the preallocated space.

Ideally, I would like to write something like:

```
MyClass* c = New(mem) MyClass(3); // use memory manager instance 'mem' and constructor 'MyClass(int)'
```

and have it translate to:

```
MyClass* c = new (mem.Reserve<MyClass>()) MyClass(3);
```

for single allocations, and:

```
MyClass* c = New(mem) MyClass[33]; //use memory manager instance 'mem' and default constructor to initialize and array of 33 MyClass objects
```

translate to:

```
MyClass* c = new (mem.Reserve<MyClass>(33)) MyClass[33];
```

The `Reserve< TYPE >(SIZE)` method is what manages the internal parameters. It reserves `(sizeof(TYPE)*(SIZE))` bytes in the preallocated memory managed by `mem` and returns the pointer of the starting address to the placement new function.

Is this a feasible operation for a macro? Or is there a better way to approach this?

I am limited to C++03 standard as that is what my ARM compiler supports.

I appreciate any advice and examples to help me understand this better!
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think so.  Everything the macro knows is inside the `()`, and `::operator new` doesn't in any situation know the type being passed.  Ergo, there's no way for the macro to find the type/extent of the thing requesting memory.

Comment: Why not simply use the function? `MyClass* c = mem.Reserve<MyClass>(33);`

Comment: I have a function 'mem.New<MyClass>(SIZE)' that runs the placement new function. My problem is that I can only hardcode the default constructor. I need to be able to call any constructor, so my thought was to eliminate the New function and have the user use placement new directly.

Comment: Or make more overloads of `New` that take parameters, [like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6beb5aa88f44d435)?  (You may want mutable reference versions as well, but that can get unwieldy quickly unless you have crafy techniques like boost do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following may help:

```
#define New(mem, Type) new (mem.Reserve<Type>()) Type
#define NewArray(mem, Type, Size) new (mem.Reserve<Type>(Size)) Type[Size]
```

Use it like:

```
MyClass* c = New(mem, MyClass)(3);       // new (mem.Reserve<MyClass>()) MyClass(3);
MyClass* c = NewArray(mem, MyClass, 33); // new (mem.Reserve<MyClass>(33)) MyClass[33];
```

Maybe defining `void* operator new(size_t n, MemoryManager& mem);` may help also (if `Reserve<MyClass>` use `MyClass` only to know its size).